# See number of live/dead tuples in MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

I'm trying to get some precise row counts for all tables, given that some have deleted rows. I have been using `sys.storage.count`. But this seems to count the deleted ones also.

I assume using `sys.storage` would be simpler and faster than looping through `count(*)` queries, though both strategies may be fine in practice.

Maybe there is some column that counts modifications so I could just subtract the two counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to know is the number of actual rows in a table, I'd recommend just using a `count(*)` query. It's very fast.  Even if you have N tables, it's easy to do a `count(*)` for each table.

`sys.storage` gives you information from the raw storage. With that, you can get pretty low-level information, but it has some edges. `sys.storage.count` returns the count in the storage, hence, indeed, it includes the delete rows since they are not actually deleted. As of Jul2021 version of MonetDB, deleted rows are automatically overwritten by new inserts (i.e. auto-vacuuming). So, to get the actual row count, you need to look up the 'deletes' from `sys.deltas('<schema>', '<table>')`. For instance:

```
sql>create table tbl (id int, city string);
operation successful
sql>insert into tbl values (1, 'London'), (2, 'Paris'), (3, 'Barcelona');
3 affected rows
sql>select * from tbl;
+------+-----------+
| id   | city      |
+======+===========+
|    1 | London    |
|    2 | Paris     |
|    3 | Barcelona |
+------+-----------+
3 tuples
sql>select schema, table, column, count from sys.storage where table='tbl';
+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| schema | table | column | count |
+========+=======+========+=======+
| sys    | tbl   | city   |     3 |
| sys    | tbl   | id     |     3 |
+--------+-------+--------+-------+
2 tuples
sql>select id, deletes from sys.deltas ('sys', 'tbl');
+-------+---------+
| id    | deletes |
+=======+=========+
| 15569 |       0 |
| 15570 |       0 |
+-------+---------+
2 tuples
```

After we delete one row, the actual row count is `sys.storage.count - sys.deltas ('sys', 'tbl').deletes`:

```
sql>delete from tbl where id = 2;
1 affected row
sql>select * from tbl;
+------+-----------+
| id   | city      |
+======+===========+
|    1 | London    |
|    3 | Barcelona |
+------+-----------+
2 tuples
sql>select schema, table, column, count from sys.storage where table='tbl';
+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| schema | table | column | count |
+========+=======+========+=======+
| sys    | tbl   | city   |     3 |
| sys    | tbl   | id     |     3 |
+--------+-------+--------+-------+
2 tuples
sql>select id, deletes from sys.deltas ('sys', 'tbl');
+-------+---------+
| id    | deletes |
+=======+=========+
| 15569 |       1 |
| 15570 |       1 |
+-------+---------+
2 tuples
```

After we insert a new row, the deleted row is overwritten:

```
sql>insert into tbl values (4, 'Praag');
1 affected row
sql>select * from tbl;
+------+-----------+
| id   | city      |
+======+===========+
|    1 | London    |
|    4 | Praag     |
|    3 | Barcelona |
+------+-----------+
3 tuples
sql>select schema, table, column, count from sys.storage where table='tbl';
+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| schema | table | column | count |
+========+=======+========+=======+
| sys    | tbl   | city   |     3 |
| sys    | tbl   | id     |     3 |
+--------+-------+--------+-------+
2 tuples
sql>select id, deletes from sys.deltas ('sys', 'tbl');
+-------+---------+
| id    | deletes |
+=======+=========+
| 15569 |       0 |
| 15570 |       0 |
+-------+---------+
2 tuples
```

So, the formula to compute the actual row count (`sys.storage.count - sys.deltas ('sys', 'tbl').deletes`) is generally applicable. `sys.deltas()` keeps stats for every column of a table, but the `count` and `deletes` are table wide, so you only need to check one column.

Comment: Thanks - very cool! Good to know that `count(*)` also can be recommended. This dead-tuple count may help if I ever want to copy a table to a new one once the dead tuples reach some threshold (I assume this a quick-and-dirty equivalent to things like `VACUUM FULL` in Postgres). I didn't know that dead rows would be overwritten by new ones - is that in the docs anywhere? Docs like [this one](https://www.monetdb.org/documentation-Jan2022/user-guide/sql-manual/transactions/) made me believe that Monet did absolutely nothing in this area (see "vacuum cleaning ... not yet available")

Comment: that info. holds for versions before Jul2021. From then on, vacuuming (of fixed sized data type) is done automatically. From Jan2022, one can manually vacuum string type columns. Documentation is a bit behind.

Comment: Ah, I see. And just to be clear, "automatically" only refers to overwriting deleted records with newly inserted records, right? That is, vacuuming wouldn't be triggered by simply having old deletions accumulated?

Comment: true, if you only delete, they're still be there.  To garbage collect them, you'll still have to inserting the surviving rows into a new table.